# Use Zend 3 Mail standalone

Tags: php, smtp, zend-framework3

I have today downloaded the latest Zend Framework Mail (so fw 3 - and hence why this question is **not** a duplicate) which is all designed to be componenty and not require the wider framework! Great! However I've started to implement it and its asking for each file such as Headers.php and "Interface 'Zend\Mail\Header\HeaderInterface' not found". I don't use composer if that changes things. Always been a files man myself.

I fully get that I can go through and grab these files into one long list of includes but is that how its designed to work and is there a better way? This one simply doesn't!

(For info I am trying to implement SMTP protocol).

Comment: HELO Antony, Zend Framework (3) now recommends using composer for autoloading.

Comment: Thanks. It always feels overcomplicated using extra tools to handle things like that!

Comment: It looks as if it would work with any  PSR-4 autoloader (under the Zend\Mail namespace).  Having said that Zend\Mail\Message uses Zend\Mime, so there are dependencies, probably less pain to wire up with composer.

Comment: I am working on a solution to that at the moment ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so in the end it doesn't look like they are as "componenty" as I expected and I needed to autoload a fair chunk of other stuff. The code I used (and its geared for Code Igniter) was:

```
require_once APPPATH.'/third_party/Zend_loader/StandardAutoloader.php';

use Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader;

$loader = new StandardAutoloader();
$loader->registerNamespace('Zend\Mail',APPPATH.'/third_party/Zend_mail');
$loader->registerNamespace('Zend\Stdlib',APPPATH.'/third_party/Zend_stdlib');
$loader->registerNamespace('Zend\Validator',APPPATH.'/third_party/Zend_validator');
$loader->registerNamespace('Zend\ServiceManager',APPPATH.'/third_party/Zend_service');
$loader->registerNamespace('Zend\Mime',APPPATH.'/third_party/Zend_mime');
require_once(APPPATH.'/third_party/Zend_interop/Interop/Container/ContainerInterface.php');

$loader->register();

use Zend\Mail;
use Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp as SmtpTransport;
use Zend\Mail\Transport\SmtpOptions;
```